# Global feature gates in Cargo

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I would like to enable a feature gate for my entire Cargo project. For example, I would like `#![feature(non_ascii_idents)]` added to every source file. Is there a place to list them in `Cargo.toml`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, though you don't add feature gates to every source file; they are *crate attributes*.  That is, you set them on the crate, not on every module.

Comment: So. Where *do* you put them in Cargo.toml?

Comment: @AhmedFasih "Is there a place to list them in `Cargo.toml`?"  "No."

Answer (score 3):

There are two types of attributes:

- file attributes (starting with `#`). They apply to the whole file only.
- crate attributes (starting with `#!`). They apply to the whole crate at once.

What you want (`#![feature(non_ascii_idents)]`) is a crate attribute, so you need to place it once at the top of the crate's *main file*. That main file is usually:

- `src/main.rs` for binaries
- `src/lib.rs` for libraries

Comment: question was old but the answer didn't suggest what to do instead.